# Execute sql native query from two entity using jpa or hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 tables, salesOrder with column "id", "customerId", "textReview(boolean)" and table SalesOrderline with column "salesOrderId", "productId". i want to change boolean data in textReview column. I got data from the client in the form is customerId and productId.

Native Query SQL that I made like this.

update sales order
set text_review = true
where
(select id from salesorder where customer_id = ?) in
(select salesorder_id from salesorderline where product_id = ?)

Is the SQL query correct?

I'm confused how to execute this query using jpa or hibernate in spring boot.

Comment: Does not look correct.  Usually the format of where is `where columnName = ... and columnName in ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL should be something like:

update salesOrder

set text_review = true where customer_id = ?

and id in (select salesorder_id from salesorderline where product_id = ?)

In JPA I don't think you need the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the native SQL query as is also in JPA/Hibernate (as long as the query itself is correct) by the following:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "<pu name>")
EntityManager em;

em.createNativeQuery("<native sql query>")
              .setParameter(1, customerId)
              // other parameters as needed
              .executeUpdate();
```

in case it is an UPDATE/DELETE query

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-

SELECT native queries can also be executed via JPA but then you will usually want to get a result list out of the query, instead of executeUpdate()

Answer (score 0):

you can write the native query as below.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(value = "update salesOrder set text_review = true where customer_id =:customerId and id salesorder_id (select salesorder_id from salesorderline where product_id =:productId)" , nativeQuery =true)
void updateTextView(@Param("customerId")String customerId, @Param("productId")String productId);
```